# ReferenceError : Cant find variable: nativeFabricUIManager

Tags: react-native

so recently this error pops up as soon as i start debugging the app, the error comes up randomly, sometimes it pops up and sometimes it wont pop up at all. I can dismiss it but it becomes annoying because it happens 80% when i started debugging
none of my codes require the 'nativeFabricUIManager' variable (i've searched using VSCode, and i found nothing on nativeFabricUIManager)

does anyone know what causes this?

Image of the error screen:

[image]